# NaN return from JavaScript function while alert is returning number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show word output of a currency number as tool tip. I want to achieve something like this `->` on hover get the value inside table, calculate word equivalent and display it as tool tip.
I am using Number to word converter function which is working fine independently. But the below code is returning Not a number although "var b" alerts to a numeric value.

```js
function getVal() {
  $('#data1 tr td.num').hover(function() {
    var a = $(this).html();
    var b = parseFloat(a.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
    alert(b); /// working fine giving number as alert 
    return parseInt(b, 10);
  });
}


/****setting title function ***/
function titleSetter(node) {

  var num2words = new NumberToWords();
  num2words.setMode("indian");

  var indian = num2words.numberToWords(getVal()); /// NaN error
  return indian;
}


/****setting title value ***/

$('.num').tooltip({
  title: titleSetter
})
```

```html
<td class="text-right num" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> 
<?php echo $fmt ->format($sum); ?></td>
```

Some help to this code or something else fulfilling my requirement is a welcome and thanks in advance

Comment: getVal() is already returning parseInt value , then what is the use of again doing  parseInt in this line
var indian = num2words.numberToWords(parseInt(getVal()));?

Comment: that is a typo. I am editing it.

Comment: @sandeepyadav Where is the library for `NumberToWords`?

Comment: Never call `parseInt` on a number!

Comment: `getVal` does not return anything? It just installs a hover listener.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: please suggest something, I have returned "b" but not working.

Comment: @sandeepyadav Did you see my answer man? What do you think?

Comment: I have seen it. I need to capture value in element on hover, then return it as b.how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `getVal` function is adding a `hover` event, which is not returning any value.

Try passing in the `text` from `titleSetter` to `getVal` like this:-

```
function getVal(text) {
    var b = parseFloat(text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
    alert(b); /// working fine giving number as alert 
    return parseInt(b, 10);
}


/****setting title function ***/
function titleSetter() {

  var num2words = new NumberToWords();
  num2words.setMode("indian");

  var text = $.trim($(this).text());

  var indian = num2words.numberToWords(getVal(text));
  return indian;
}


/****setting title value ***/

$('.num').tooltip({
  title: titleSetter
})
```

Comment: Thanks bro you have solved my problem. I am learning java script and was struggling from last three days.